# Merge Overlapping Intervals in PysPark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, intervals

I have a DataFrame like this (but much larger):

```
id   start    end
0    10       20
1    11       13
2    14       18
3    22       30
4    25       27
5    28       31
```

I am trying to efficiently merge overlapping intervals in PySpark, while saving in a new column 'ids', which intervals were merged, so that it looks like this:

```
start    end   ids
10       20    [0,1,2]
22       31    [3,4,5]
```

Visualisation:
from:

[image: AS-IS]
to:
[image: TO-BE]

Can I do this without using an udf?

edit: the order of id and start are not necessarily the same.

Comment: can we assume that id 0 will always be the earliest start and the last id will always have the latest start (and same for everything in between)? e.g. the order for id and start are the same?

Comment: @ScootCork unfortunately not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window function to compare previous rows with current row, to build a column that determine if current row is the start of a new interval, then sum over this column to build a interval id. Then you group by this interval id to get your final dataframe.

If you call `input_df` your input dataframe, the code will be as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

all_previous_rows_window = Window \
  .orderBy('start') \
  .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

result = input_df \
  .withColumn('max_previous_end', F.max('end').over(all_previous_rows_window)) \
  .withColumn('interval_change', F.when(
    F.col('start') > F.lag('max_previous_end').over(Window.orderBy('start')), 
    F.lit(1)
  ).otherwise(F.lit(0))) \
  .withColumn('interval_id', F.sum('interval_change').over(all_previous_rows_window)) \
  .drop('interval_change', 'max_previous_end') \
  .groupBy('interval_id') \
  .agg(
    F.collect_list('id').alias('ids'),
    F.min('start').alias('start'),
    F.max('end').alias('end')
  ).drop('interval_id')
```

So you can merge your intervals without any user-defined function. However, every time we use a window, code is executed on only on one executor, as our window don't have partitions.